# C++ to Matlab online converter

Tags: gratis, c++, c, programming, matlab

I'm asked to write a small project in Matlab. I don't know Matlab and I don't want to learn it and I'm on Linux.

Is there a free online C++ (or python) converter to Matlab? It's a small project but the professor only knows Matlab. I know that C++ and Matlab are similar so converting syntax shouldn't be a big deal.

Please don't recommend octave, I'll have to learn Matlab syntax if I want to use it.

Comment: I don't think C++ is remotely like MATLAB. It is possible to wrap C++ up so that it is callable from MATLAB so this might minimize the amount of MATLAB necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Universal-transpiler](https://jarble.github.io/transpiler/javascript/js_transpiler/test_parser.html#%7B%22inputText%22%3A%22%5Cndouble%20distance_formula(double%20x1%2Cdouble%20y1%2Cdouble%20x2%2Cdouble%20y2)%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20return%20sqrt(pow(x1-x2%2C2)%2Bpow(xy-y2%2C2))%3B%5Cn%7D%22%2C%22inputLang%22%3A%22c%2B%2B%22%2C%22outputLang%22%3A%22matlab%22%7D), it is possible to convert a very limited subset of C++ into equivalent Matlab code.

As an example, this is some C++ code:

```
double distance_formula(double x1,double y1,double x2,double y2){
    return sqrt(pow(x1-x2,2)+pow(xy-y2,2));
```

and this is the translator's output:

```
function distance_formula(x1,y1,x2,y2) 
    return sqrt(((x1-x2)^(2))+((xy-y2)^(2)));
end
```

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer since I'm no longer using matlab and since this this the only answer available. Thank you

Comment: URL of the Universal-transpiler is as below:
https://jarble.github.io/transpiler/javascript/js_transpiler/test_parser.html#%7B%22inputText%22%3A%22%5Cndouble%20distance_formula(double%20x1%2Cdouble%20y1%2Cdouble%20x2%2Cdouble%20y2)%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20return%20sqrt(pow(x1-x2%2C2)%2Bpow(xy-y2%2C2))%3B%5Cn%7D%22%2C%22inputLang%22%3A%22c%2B%2B%22%2C%22outputLang%22%3A%22matlab%22%7D I pasted a small piece of C++ code into a box labelled as "Code to translate". But next what to do as there is no button for running it to get the output Code in Matlab?

Comment: @SadiqAkbar This compiler only works with a small subset of C++, so that code might not have been translated.